# I can not open the chrome browser using latest webdriver manager 5.6.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver-manager

I am getting below error on running my testng test:

*"org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'xxxxx', ip: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
Build info: version: '4.15.0', revision: '1d14b5521b'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.5', java.version: '21.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: /Application"*

**Below are the details of versions I am using:**
Chrome browser version: 119
Webdrivermanager: 5.6.0
TestNg version: 7.8.0
Selenium-Java: 4.15.0
JDK: Tried 21, 18 and 11 but facing same issue every time

**Here is the code I am trying to run:**

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class okta1 {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    static void setupClass() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().setup();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    void setupTest() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setCapability("browserVersion", "119.0.6045.105");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    @AfterTest
    void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        // Exercise
        driver.get("https://bonigarcia.dev/selenium-webdriver-java/");
        String title = driver.getTitle();

        // Verify
        // assertThat(title).contains("Selenium WebDriver");
    }


}
```

**
Here is the pom.xml:**

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Teams-Automation-Framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.15.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>```



Tried changing different version of JDK and webdriver manager but still getting same error on every attempt
````

Comment: You need to add the slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar file to your classpath

Comment: Thanks @bhairu . . . after adding above suggested dependency it has finally started working now :)